# Update rest of the values of the JSON dataset to a specific value?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON dataset like below:

```
data: {
        datasets: [{
                data: [2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
            }]
        }
```

From the `#dim` input, I'm trying to update a particular value of this set and also change the rest of them to `0`. Like if `#dim` value is `2`, then the dataset will update to `[0, 5, 0, 0, 0]`.

I'm using the following code to change one particular value from the input. But how can I update the rest of them to `0`?

```
$(".button").click(function() {
            var dim = $('#dim').val();

            data.datasets[2].data['' + dim + ''] = 5; //If dim value is 2, it makes data: [2, 5, 5, 7, 8]

            //I need some code here that'll change the rest of the values to 0. That is [0, 5, 0, 0, 0]
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, and yes, it was a typo. @brk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to the `0` th index from `data.datasets` instead of `data.datasets[2]`.
If the input type is `text` it will give you a string so use `parseInt` to convert that to number. Also the array index starts from `0`. So if you wish to change second element in the array you need to target the element which is in index 1.

```js
let data = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
  }]
}
$(".button").click(function() {
  var dim = parseInt($('#dim').val(), 10) - 1;
  //setting all other value to 0
  data.datasets[0].data.forEach(function(item, index) {
    data.datasets[0].data[index] = 0
  })
  data.datasets[0].data['' + dim + ''] = 5;
  console.log(data)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='dim'>
<button type='button' class='button'>Click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set all array values to **zero** first using `new Array(5).fill(0)` and then apply your code to update the 2nd element.

To set all values to zero try,

```js
const js_obj = {
    data: {
      datasets: [{
        data: [2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
      }]
    }
  }  
let dim = 1; // as you're grabbing dim value from the button click
js_obj.data.datasets[0].data = new Array(5).fill(0)
js_obj.data.datasets[0].data[dim] = 5;
console.log(js_obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    var dim = $('#dim').val();
    if(dim) {
        for(var i=0;i<data.datasets[2].length;i++)
            data.datasets[2].data[i] = 0;
        data.datasets[2].data[dim - 1] = 5;
    }
}
```